# Populate a column in a pandas df based on a selected column containing a certain substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
     id         text
0   100  Donut/cookie, ; penguin
1   101  donut cake! penguinz
2   102  pizza!!!? donut cakepeanut

----------------------------------

data = [[100,'Donut/cookie, ; penguin'],
    [101,'donut cake! penguinz'],
    [102,'pizza!!!? donut cakepeanut']
   ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id','text'])
```

I would to add several columns to my df depending on whether specific substrings exist in the `text` column

So something like this:

```
    id         text                   donut       cookie      penguin  pizza
0   100  Donut/cookie, ; penguin        yes        yes          yes      no   
1   101  donut cake! penguinz           yes        no           yes      no
2   102  pizza!!!? donut cakepenguin    yes        no           yes      yes
```

I just need it yes/no if the substring exists, delimitation and white spaces don't really matter. Also it would be really helpful if it wasn't case sensitive

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? For instance, pandas `series.str.contains()` would be a good place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[100, 'Donut/cookie, ; penguin'],
        [101, 'donut cake! penguinz'],
        [102, 'pizza!!!? donut cakepeanut']
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'text'])


def check(df, key):
    return df['text'].apply(lambda x: "yes" if key in x.lower() else "no")


df['donut'] = check(df, 'donut')
df['cookie'] = check(df, 'cookie')
df['penguin'] = check(df, 'penguin')
df['pizza'] = check(df, 'pizza')
```

Comment: is there a way to skip null values if they're null

Comment: you can use fillna("") to replace null value to empty string. Then by using condition if string is empty do nothing create empty cell

Comment: apply(lambda x: "yes" if key in x.lower() else (None if x == '' else "no")) like this? @Mazhar Hossain

Comment: yes that's the way, but I don't think pranthesis is required (for last if else combination)

Answer (score 1):

You can create the `list` of key word you interested on, then do `str.contains`

```
keylist = ['donut', 'cookie', 'penguin', 'pizza']
for x in keylist:
    df[x] = df.text.str.contains(x,case=False).map({True:'yes',False:'no'})
    
df
Out[379]: 
    id                        text donut cookie penguin pizza
0  100     Donut/cookie, ; penguin   yes    yes     yes    no
1  101        donut cake! penguinz   yes     no     yes    no
2  102  pizza!!!? donut cakepeanut   yes     no      no   yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex for that and `pandas.get_dummies`:

```
words = ['donut', 'cookie', 'penguin', 'pizza']
regex = '(%s)' % '|'.join(words)

import re
df2 = (pd.get_dummies(df['text'].str.extractall(regex, flags=re.I)[0])
       .groupby(level=0).sum()
       .replace({1:'yes', 0:'no'})
      )
```

It should be
output:

```
    id                        text cookie donut penguin pizza
0  100     Donut/cookie, ; penguin    yes    no     yes    no
1  101        donut cake! penguinz     no   yes     yes    no
2  102  pizza!!!? donut cakepeanut     no   yes      no   yes
```